# The reason why $\frac{a+b}{2}=c$ in a quadratic.

Tags: calculus

Question: In a quadratic, I learned that there's a point $c$ on the graph that has the same slope (or derivative?) as the slope that any two points $a$ and $b$ on the graph form, and that is expressed as $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c).$$  And, I learned that $\frac{a+b}{2}=c$.  My tutor said he will show me the proof when he comes back, but I'm curious. Can somebody prove that thing?.

Comment: This is the mean value theorem:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: yeah I know. But why is it that (a+b)/2=c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the result is true, then you can prove it by direct verification:

Guide:

- Let the quadratic function be $f(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma$
- Compute $f'(x)$.
- Compute $f'(c)= f'\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.
- Compute $f(b)$, $f(a)$ and then $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, verify that it is equal to the expression that you obtained above.

Note:
$$f(b)-f(a)=\alpha(b^2-a^2)+\beta(b-a)$$

The following identities might help you:

$$b^2-a^2=(b-a)(b+a)$$

Edit after OP attempted:

\begin{align}\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} &=\frac{\alpha(b^2-a^2)+\beta(b-a)}{b-a}\\
&=\alpha(b+a)+\beta\\
&= 2\alpha \left( \frac{a+b}2\right)+\beta \\
&= 2\alpha(c)+\beta \\
&= f'(c)\end{align}

Comment: But how would you generalize it? I learned that it works for all points!

Comment: that is why we left it in terms of $a$ and $b$ rather than specific values.

Comment: wait, what expression are you talking about? number 3 step?

Comment: In the previous step, you have computed $f'(x)$ right, whenever you see $x$, replace it by $\frac{a+b}2$.

Comment: I mean the last sentence.

Comment: what's the expresion obtained above?

Comment: $f'(c)(b-a)$. if the equation is true, then we should have $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$.

Comment: edited more and hopefully it makes it easier to verify.

Comment: .......... I ended up with alpha*beta+alpha*a=2alpha*c. I don't understand why it does not work.  but thanks a lot!

Comment: if you include more working, I can look at what went wrong.

Comment: beta(b-a)+2alphac(b-a)=alpha(b^2-a^20+beta(b-a) alphabeta+alphaa+beta=2alphac+beta. (after dividing by b-a.)

Comment: first equation is f'(c)(b-a), and the second is the remaining.

Comment: learning [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) helps you to type maths on this site. Also, try to include your working when you post a question or it might get downvotes or being closed.

Comment: okay, thanks for advice!

Comment: I have included the answer after you show that you attempted it.

Comment: oh wait I thought it was f(b)-f(a)! I calculated that way!

Comment: ok now I understand thanks a bunch